# Using any Jquery AJAX requests to load PHP script cause script to be returned and not run by server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, xampp

I am using the following code:

```
            $.post( "includes/modules/list.php" );
```

And I have tried the following:

```
            jQuery("#empty").load("/includes/modules/list.php", {}, function() { 
                refreshlist();
            });
```

And:

```
            $.post("/includes/modules/list.php",function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
```

It was working fine on **IIS** but after switching to **Apache** (which I thought would actually work properly) it stopped working. 
Now the **IIS** server was configured by **Plesk**, so maybe that has something to do with it?

This is my first post here, so please excuse any of my errors.

Edit: I am did this with XAMPP, meaning that PHP was tied up with it. PHP scripts do work, I did test hello world things and they all work, but when I try to call it, it won't work.

I am using Windows. I am seriously debating just rewriting this in ASP.NET and installing back IIS but this is taking so much time already. This is a personal project but I really do want to have this work and be able to use PHP since that is the most mainstream option.

Another Edit: This is my php -i dump as requested (since I have no idea where to look)

```
SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: a915862ec47f9589309acc4996ca8f6179788746 $
Schema support => enabled

soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, Spl
Observer, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException,
 BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryItera
tor, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIte
rator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthExcep
tion, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBo
undsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeExce
ption, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilter
Iterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIterator
Iterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeE
xception, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHea
p, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStac
k, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7-dev
SQLite Library => 3.8.4.3

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=hr
ef,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlrpc

core library version => xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version => 0.51
author => Dan Libby
homepage => http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by => Epinions.com

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.27
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.7.8
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 0.8.16

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: a9db166c839b24cbebccad95120bd535e720038f $
Zip version => 1.12.4
Libzip version => 0.11.2

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.7.3
Linked Version => 1.2.7.3

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
ALLUSERSPROFILE => C:\ProgramData
AMDAPPSDKROOT => C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\
APPDATA => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Roaming
asl.log => Destination=file
CommonProgramFiles => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86) => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432 => C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME => AURORA51
ComSpec => C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK => NO
GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT => 50
HOMEDRIVE => C:
HOMEPATH => \Users\Xilence
HuluDesktopPath => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Local\HuluDesktop\instances\0.9.14.1
\HuluDesktop.exe
LOCALAPPDATA => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER => \\AURORA51
MIBDIRS => C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs
MYSQL_HOME => C:\xampp\mysql\bin
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS => 4
OPENSSL_CONF => C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
OS => Windows_NT
Path => ;C:\xampp\;C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\perl\site\bin;C:\xampp\perl\bin;C:\xamp
p\apache\bin;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\FileZillaFTP;C:\xampp\MercuryMail;C:\xa
mpp\sendmail;C:\xampp\webalizer;C:\xampp\tomcat\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\iis e
xpress\PHP\v5.6;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD A
PP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\zpanel\bin\apache\bin;C:
\zpanel\bin\mysql\bin;C:\zpanel\bin\php;C:\zpanel\bin\wget;C:\zpanel\bin\bind\bi
n;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (
x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Co
rporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C
:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologi
es\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Plat
form Installer\;;C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server
PATHEXT => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PHPRC => C:\xampp\php
PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR => C:\xampp\php
PHP_PEAR_CFG_DIR => C:\xampp\php\cfg
PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR => C:\xampp\php\data
PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR => C:\xampp\php\docs
PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR => C:\xampp\php\pear
PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN => C:\xampp\php\php.exe
PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR => C:\xampp\php
PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR => C:\xampp\php\tests
PHP_PEAR_WWW_DIR => C:\xampp\php\www
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE => x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 => AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER => AMD64 Family 16 Model 4 Stepping 3, AuthenticAMD
PROCESSOR_LEVEL => 16
PROCESSOR_REVISION => 0403
ProgramData => C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles => C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86) => C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 => C:\Program Files
PROMPT => Xilence@AURORA51$S$P$_#$S
PSModulePath => C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC => C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME => Console
SystemDrive => C:
SystemRoot => C:\Windows
TEMP => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP => C:\xampp\tmp
USERDOMAIN => Aurora51
USERNAME => Xilence
USERPROFILE => C:\Users\Xilence
windir => C:\Windows

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["ALLUSERSPROFILE"] => C:\ProgramData
_SERVER["AMDAPPSDKROOT"] => C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\
_SERVER["APPDATA"] => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Roaming
_SERVER["asl_log"] => Destination=file
_SERVER["CommonProgramFiles"] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
_SERVER["CommonProgramFiles(x86)"] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
_SERVER["CommonProgramW6432"] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
_SERVER["COMPUTERNAME"] => AURORA51
_SERVER["ComSpec"] => C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
_SERVER["FP_NO_HOST_CHECK"] => NO
_SERVER["GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT"] => 50
_SERVER["HOMEDRIVE"] => C:
_SERVER["HOMEPATH"] => \Users\Xilence
_SERVER["HuluDesktopPath"] => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Local\HuluDesktop\instanc
es\0.9.14.1\HuluDesktop.exe
_SERVER["LOCALAPPDATA"] => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Local
_SERVER["LOGONSERVER"] => \\AURORA51
_SERVER["MIBDIRS"] => C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs
_SERVER["MYSQL_HOME"] => C:\xampp\mysql\bin
_SERVER["NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"] => 4
_SERVER["OPENSSL_CONF"] => C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
_SERVER["OS"] => Windows_NT
_SERVER["Path"] => ;C:\xampp\;C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\perl\site\bin;C:\xampp\perl\
bin;C:\xampp\apache\bin;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\FileZillaFTP;C:\xampp\Mercur
yMail;C:\xampp\sendmail;C:\xampp\webalizer;C:\xampp\tomcat\bin;C:\Program Files
(x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
(x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\zpanel\bin\ap
ache\bin;C:\zpanel\bin\mysql\bin;C:\zpanel\bin\php;C:\zpanel\bin\wget;C:\zpanel\
bin\bind\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86
)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Syst
em32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
 Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server;C:\Program Files\Microso
ft\Web Platform Installer\;;C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server
_SERVER["PATHEXT"] => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
_SERVER["PHPRC"] => C:\xampp\php
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_CFG_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php\cfg
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php\data
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php\docs
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php\pear
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN"] => C:\xampp\php\php.exe
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php\tests
_SERVER["PHP_PEAR_WWW_DIR"] => C:\xampp\php\www
_SERVER["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"] => x86
_SERVER["PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"] => AMD64
_SERVER["PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"] => AMD64 Family 16 Model 4 Stepping 3, Authentic
AMD
_SERVER["PROCESSOR_LEVEL"] => 16
_SERVER["PROCESSOR_REVISION"] => 0403
_SERVER["ProgramData"] => C:\ProgramData
_SERVER["ProgramFiles"] => C:\Program Files (x86)
_SERVER["ProgramFiles(x86)"] => C:\Program Files (x86)
_SERVER["ProgramW6432"] => C:\Program Files
_SERVER["PROMPT"] => Xilence@AURORA51$S$P$_#$S
_SERVER["PSModulePath"] => C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
_SERVER["PUBLIC"] => C:\Users\Public
_SERVER["SESSIONNAME"] => Console
_SERVER["SystemDrive"] => C:
_SERVER["SystemRoot"] => C:\Windows
_SERVER["TEMP"] => C:\Users\Xilence\AppData\Local\Temp
_SERVER["TMP"] => C:\xampp\tmp
_SERVER["USERDOMAIN"] => Aurora51
_SERVER["USERNAME"] => Xilence
_SERVER["USERPROFILE"] => C:\Users\Xilence
_SERVER["windir"] => C:\Windows
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] =>
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] =>
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] =>
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] =>
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] =>
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1420338712.5439
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1420338712
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 0

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.

Xilence@AURORA51 c:\xampp
#
```

Comment: it does sound like your server isn't configured to return php scripts properly, yeah...

Comment: run `php -i` in your server to check php is set properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. It was really dumb of me but somewhere in my editing I removed the `<?php` part at the beginning of the document and only had `<?` so that had caused it not to be parsed by the server, anyway... thank you so much for your help everyone! Should have just put code here in the first place. I will next time. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question but what I think you are asking is that when your php page is called it returns the php script rather than executing it (I do not see why Ajax is important here - I assume the same happens if you browse directly to the php page in your browser?)

My first question would be whether you have installed php on the server as this is the usual problem in this situation?  If not, assuming it it's Linux then run either apt-get install php5 (if it is ubuntu, Debian or similar like Mint) or yum install php5 (if it is Redhat Fedora or Centos)

If php is installed, check your httpd.conf (usually in /etc/httpd/conf) and check that the php module is being loaded - I won't go into loads of detail about this as Google is full of good info on Apache configs.

Also check your php page is executable as it is a script (ls -l yourphppagename.php and look for the x characters on the left)

Comment: Ok let's break this down into two problems - the JQuery post and the php page.So if you browse to includes/modules/list.php directly in your browser what happens?  Also note in your two examples one says includes and one says /includes ... Probably doesn't matter but just in case it does break something.

Comment: When I browse it just shows the code, zero execution. So when I do a Jquery load and ask it to check if it finished and do so and so command when it finishes, it returns the entire darned code instead! Also I know that the the / means something sometimes because the interpretation on some servers can be terrible depending on the server but I think I tried all options even ./includes/modules/list.php etc.

Comment: If it comes back with code when you browse direct then the problem isn't JQuery.  Because php commands work then php is installed ok.  Try to make a file on the server that contains just <?php phpinfo(); ?> (make sure the file name ends .php) and try to browse to just that.  It should output a big long table Until that works, focus on just that and ignore JQuery and client side scripting.  If it doesn't work, come back and say, but also a quick google for php files just display as code will give loads of suggestions (file permissions, httpd.conf, etc).

Comment: My money is on you not having the AddModule line enabled in httpd.conf but from memory I can't remember the line you need and I'm just replying on my phone so browsing is very slow to get it at the moment (Google will know)

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?> works. Odd. I can upload the file for you to see if you want. Here you can browse my entire setup. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ftcr62a8yrw51q1/AAAn9HAjFzt4MwUg1Mz5bnKIa?dl=0 Let me know if it works for you to check out! Go to includes/modules/list.php

Comment: Yes that is very strange! I'm travelling for the next 48 hours but if I'm in an airport lounge with wifi I'll try to have a look for you

Comment: Solved: <? didn't have PHP next to it. My server didn't feel like recognizing it was PHP. lol